# ExtJS - Where to put external libraries

Tags: javascript, extjs

If in my project I need to use external libraries, lets say JQuery, where should I put these libraries in the ExtJS application project directory structure?

Is `PROJECT/resources/scripts/` OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example create a `js` folder on the same level as ExtJS `app` folder, and if you put a file `script.js` here, open your `app.json` file, locate the part where `"js":` array is, and add your file like this:

```
"js": [
    {
        "path": "${framework.dir}/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js"
    },
    {
        "path": "app.js",
        "bundle": true
    },
    { // add this part
        "path": "js/script.js"
    }
],
```